# VBA equivalent to VLOOKUP with multiple "col_index_num"s

Tags: vba, excel, syntax, vlookup

what is the syntax for writing vlookup in vba where you want to return multiple columns?  My code:

```
For i = 2 To lastrow
   wsTEMP.Range(Cells(i, 16), Cells(i, 20)) = _
       Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
           Workbooks("template.xlsm").Worksheets("Qry").Cells(i, 1), _
           Workbooks("template.xlsm").Worksheets("Qry").Range("A:G"), _
           XXXhow do I write this??XXX, _
           0)
Next i
```

**EDIT: Further Clarification**

If you were doing this with a normal vlookup it would look like:

Select a range, let's say A1:E1, then

```
=VLOOKUP(G2,range,{3,4,5,6,7},0)
```

So that {3,4,5,6,7} would return the results of multiple columns when you hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter (they'd go in the A1, B1, etc. that I selected before doing the vlookup.  How do I do that in VBA?  Please let me know if I need to provide further clarification, sorry.

Comment: Can you provide some additional clarification? Are you trying to populate  the five cells all at once?

Comment: And how would a VLOOKUP with "multiple col_index_num's" even work as a regular Excel formula? `WorksheetFunction` works just like the worksheet function; if it can't be done with a VLOOKUP, it can't be done with a VLOOKUP *in VBA*.

Comment: added clarification, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ways to do this.

1) If you were to record a macro it would give you the FormulaArray method of the Range object:

```
Range("I4:M4").FormulaArray = "=VLOOKUP(G2,range,{3,4,5,6,7},0)"
```

2) Alternately you can use Application.Evaluate

```
Range("I6:M6") = Application.Evaluate("VLOOKUP(G2,range,{3,4,5,6,7},0)")
```